# Why Mysql reads more rows than i set limit?

Tags: mysql, database, web

```
explain select * from user where nick = 'vertichvostka' limit 1;
```

Table has ~3 million rows.
Why mysql reads 21012 rows if i set limit 1?

[image]

Comment: limit just limits the return amount of rows, not how many to read from

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs I think the OP is asking why mySql finds all the rows that match the `where` clause if it just can stop after the first match as there is a `limit` clause in the query

Comment: @Paolo Ah I see well for the same reason I posted above^^ haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standing to this old article: [MySQL EXPLAIN limits and errors](https://www.percona.com/blog/2006/07/24/mysql-explain-limits-and-errors/)

> **LIMIT is not taken into account while estimating number of rows** Even if you have LIMIT which restricts how many rows will be examined MySQL will still print full number.

Of course when you actually execute the query it will stop after the number of rows specified with the `limit` clause:

From: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/limit-optimization.html

> As soon as MySQL has sent the required number of rows to the client, it aborts the query